# Publishing failed due to Transaction was deadlocked on lock

Tags: 2013, publishing

i m getting this error while publishing components

```
Transaction (Process ID 241) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
```

**Update**

i m getting this error randomly if i republish the component it get published.We r using single deployer and database is MICROSOFT SQL

Comment: You should provide some more information. Do you get this error every time, or randomly ? Do you have any other useful data from your deployer log ? Are you deploying to one deployer, or multiple deployers ? I've seen similar issues when we publish to two deployers who try to update the same broker db, but without more information from your setup, it's difficult to help you solve the problem.

Comment: Where is this error occurring? On the CM or CD side?

Comment: The error is on CM side

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check the number of threads that you have configured for rendering. There was a change from 2011 to 2013 on how the threads are managed. If publishing is under load, and you have more threads than your DB can handle, this may be the cause. Just a thought...

Comment: After reducing thread on CMS server for both rendering and deploying it is working fine now

Comment: i  changed No of thread for rendering as 1 and No of thread for deploying as 3 but sometime it still give this error.